# $n$ players are each dealt two cards — what's the probability that $k$ of them have a pair?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Each of $n\leq26$ players is dealt $2$ cards from a standard $52$-card poker deck. What is $\textrm{P}\left(n,k\right)$, the probability that exactly $k$ of the $n$ players have a pair?

(A pair is a hand like $8 \clubsuit, 8 \heartsuit$ or $K \clubsuit, K \diamondsuit$.)

---

This question was previously asked at Poker.SE without a satisfactory answer: https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/4087/probability-of-x-pocket-pairs-at-a-table-of-n-people-nlhe

Comment: What is a pair?

Comment: So any $2$ of the cards in all the $4$ cards of ace for example are a pair?

Comment: @Haran: Affirmative.

Comment: Right now I do not believe in the existence of an elegant solution and a closed formula. It has happpened before though that I was wrong in a sortlike disbelief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let us compute $f(m)$, the number of ways to deal two cards to each of $m$ people which are all pairs. We can do this using a computer as follows. If we further let $f(m,r)$ be the probability that all $m$ people have pairs when dealt from a deck of $4r$ cards, then
$$
f(m,r) = r\binom42\big(f(m-1,r-1)+(m-1)f(m-2,r-1)\big)
$$
The first summand accounts for ways where the first player gets a pair that no one else has, and the second accounts for ways where some other player also gets that pair. The above recursive equation allows you to compute $f(m)=f(m,13)$ quickly using dynamic programming.

Next, use the [generalized principle of inclusion exclusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1808129/generalised-inclusion-exclusion-principle). Letting $E_i$ be the event that the $i^{th}$ player has a pair, then
\begin{align}
P(n,k)
&=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^{i-k}\binom{i}{k}\binom{n}{i}\mathbb P(E_1\cap E_2\cap \dots \cap E_i)\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^{i-k}\binom{i}{k}\binom{n}{i}\frac{f(i)}{\frac{52!}{2^i(52-2i)!}}
\end{align}

You can see this in action [here](https://repl.it/@mearnest/n-players-k-pairs), just click the run button at the top and enter your desired value of $n$.

---

Also, there is the following "closed form" for $P(n,k)$:

$$
\boxed{P(n,k) = \binom{n}{k}\sum_{i=k}^n(-1)^{i-k}\binom{n-k}{i-k}\frac{2^i(52-2i)!}{52!}\cdot i!\cdot [x^i](1+6x+3x^2)^{13}}
$$
Here, the notation $[x^i]f(x)$ means the coefficient of $x^i$ in the polynomial $f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

The probability that a particular player is dealt a pair is $\frac{4-1}{52-1}=\frac{1}{17}$ so the expected number of pairs is $\frac{n}{17}$

I suspect the distribution is not going to be far away from Binomial with parameters $n$ and $p=\frac{1}{17}$. This is not quite correct (for example when $n=26$ the probability of exactly $25$ pairs is $0$ rather than $4.24\times 10^{−30}$) but I would be surprised if it were substantially misleading

As an example, here are a couple of simulations of $100000$ million deals to $6$ players

```
Pairs                    0        1         2         3         4         5         6 
Simulation 1            69459    26065     4094      367       13         2         0
Simulation 2            69675    25918     4063      329       15         0         0
Binomial probability  0.695066 0.260650 0.040727 0.003394 0.000159 0.0000040 0.00000004
```

and, given the uncertainty of simulation, these do not look noticeably different.  The five pocket pairs out of six seen at [the link in your link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wTmvW5hiJ-4) was indeed unlikely