# what is the probability of concreate cardinality of intersection of k subsets of set?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given set $S$, where $|S| = N$, and drawn randomly $k$ subsets of $S$: $a_1, a_2, a_3, ..., a_k$ with cardinalities: $n_1, n_2, n_3, ..., n_k$. What is the probability that the intersection of $a_1, a_2, a_3, ..., a_k$ will have the cardinality equal (or equal and greater) to p (which is parameter).

The problem I encountered is that when I try to count all possible subsets of given cardinality, for the denominator of probability I get:

$$\prod_{i=1}^k\binom{N}{n_i}$$

which I believe is correct. But when i try to count such examples that has cardinality of intersection at least $p$ (to put in in numerator) then I can come up only with this: $\binom{N}{p}$ which is number of possibilities to draw the intersection, and then $\prod_{i=1}^k\binom{N-p}{n_i-p}$ representing number of possibilities of drawing rest of the subsets. Unfortunately this is not correct approach because resultig formula:

$$\frac{\binom{N}{p}\prod_{i=1}^k\binom{N-p}{n_i-p}}{\prod_{i=1}^k\binom{N}{n_i}}$$

is sometimes bigger than 1.0 for some $p=0, 1, 2, 3, ..., N$. I think the reason is that when i first draw intersection (eg. {1,2,3}), and then draw rest of the set (eg. {4,5}) I get a result ({1,2,3,4,5}) which I count multiple times (eg. when I draw intersection {3,4,5} and rest {1,2}). How to correct the numerator of formula to count every case only once?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Can you please explain what do you mean by "power"? By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on [ask], on [formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and on writing down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

If your question is clear and focused on your specific difficulty and you show your effort in solving the problem, it's more likely to get good and helping answers.

Comment: You should replace "power" by "number of elements" or "cardinality".

Comment: Besides, what is your work on the subject ?

Comment: I fixed formating and also bad translation. What do you mean by my work? My tries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done thus far is fine, but you need to use inclusion/exclusion in your numerator. So instead of:

$$\frac{\binom{N}{p}\prod_{i=1}^k\binom{N-p}{n_i-p}}{\prod_{i=1}^k\binom{N}{n_i}}$$
you instead need:

$$\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{j=p}^N (-1)^{j-p} \binom{j}{p} \binom{N}{j} \prod_{i=1}^k\binom{N-j}{n_i-j}}{\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^k\binom{N}{n_i}}$$

with the convention that ${a \choose b}=0$ for all $b < 0$.

Edit:

DANGIT! Realize I made a mistake, but cannot fix it right now. Inclusion/exclusion is the right way to go, but there is a missing factor in the numerator. I will fix later this evening, if another less confused combinatorialist does not fix it first.

Edit:

Shoot, that's what I get for trying to do this too quickly. Apologies. For each element $i$ of the index set $S$, define the set $A_i$ to be the set of all selections such that $i$ is contained in $a_1 \cap a_2 \cdots \cap a_k$. We are seeking the number of selections that are contained in exactly $p$ of these sets $A_i$.

We use a standard generalization of inclusion/exclusion (see for example [joriki's excellent description](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1808129/generalised-inclusion-exclusion-principle)) for this count. Using his notation, fulfilling a condition $A_i$ means having a selection of $a_1, a_2, \ldots a_k$ in the set $A_i$. The number of selections fulfilling $j$ conditions is uniform regardless of which conditions are chosen, namely $$\prod_{i=1}^k\binom{N-j}{n_i-j}$$

Therefore, we can use the last of joriki's formulae to give the number of ways to have an intersection size of exactly $p$ (note: The $j$ in joriki's formula is our $p$, and his $k$ is our $j$):
$$\displaystyle \sum_{j=p}^N (-1)^{j-p} \binom{j}{p} \binom{N}{j} \prod_{i=1}^k\binom{N-j}{n_i-j}$$

This is the numerator of our probability.

Comment: I need some explanation

Comment: Will add to answer...just a moment.

Comment: I have two questions to that. is this the "equal" case or "equal or greater"? By this I mean is this probability of intersection being exactly $p$ elements or being at least $p$? Is that exclusion/inclusion rule, which i dont much understand yet, to do the "equal" case? Could it get any simplier (with less computational complexity than $O(n^2))$ for "equal or greater" case?

Comment: This form of inclusion/exclusion does the "equal" case, i.e., intersection size is exactly $p$. I do not believe for this problem there is a simpler formula for "equal or greater", but there may be some intuition I don't see.

Comment: using this python code to test the formula I get negative probabilities:
https://pastebin.com/TmpQRYFQ
for example for N=37, ni=[21, 27, 24, 7, 31, 21], p=1 i get prob~= -1.73

Comment: I calculated a probability of about 0.41 using Magma, which does arbitrary precision integer arithmetic. Is Python using the Gamma function to approximate the binomial coefficients? If so, the values it produces for binomials with a negative on the bottom may not be 0.

Comment: I made a operator precedence error writing python implementation, namely in numerator I did $-(1^{j-p})$ instead of $(-1)^{j-p}$. Now probabilities are in correct range and sums up to 1 for random batch I generated. I'm really grateful for your help and I already have marked your answer as proper solution. But can you sacrifice a couple more minutes and make me understand please? You already have my gratitude till the day I die but I offer you endless gratitude* 

*(if afterworld exists)

Comment: I'm glad to take a bit more time, but need to know which specific part is confusing. Is it the generalized inclusion/exclusion formula? The specifics of how it is applied to this problem?

Comment: I understand denominator. Also I understand why cardinality of union of two (not necessarily disjoint) sets is $|a \cup b| = |a| + |b| - |a \cap b|$. Similarly I understand why cardinality of union of 3 sets is $|a \cup b \cup c| = |a| + |b| +|c| - |a \cap b| - |b \cap c| - |c \cap a| + |a \cap b \cap c|$. Also I think I know how this generalizes on greater number of sets. Still dont understand how to apply this to get our numerator.