# Find number of red balls after K turns if you paint Q balls from a bag of N distinct ones

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, binomial-coefficients, inclusion-exclusion, coupon-collector

This was a question from Infinix Hiring challenge, which ended few days ago.

You have `N` distinct white balls, and want to paint balls in a red color, instead of painting all of them simultaneously, you decide to take turns. You paint the balls by following these steps:

1. Choose `Q` balls from the bag
2. Paint the `Q` with red color
3. Put them back into the bag

**Note:** Among the chosen `Q`, red balls remain red but white ones are converted to red
You take exactly `K` turns. In other words, you follow the steps `K` times. Given `N`, `Q`, `K`, tell how no.of ways each number of balls are colored after `K` turns. Your task is to determine the number of red balls in the bag after `K` turns.

Two ways are considered different if the set of selected balls differ in at least one of the `K` turns.

**Sample Explanation:**
Lets say N = 3, Q = 2, K = 2, then there are 3 balls in the bag, you take 2 turns, and in each you chose 2 balls.

Lets number them 1 to 3, The possible ways are,

```
(1,2),(1,2) - Total colored are 2 - (1,2)
(1,2),(1,3) - Total colored are 3 - (1,2,3)
(1,2),(2,3) - Total colored are 3 - (1,2,3)
(1,3),(1,2) - Total colored are 3 - (1,2,3)
(1,3),(1,3) - Total colored are 2 - (1,3)
(1,3),(2,3) - Total colored are 3 - (1,2,3)
(2,3),(1,2) - Total colored are 3 - (1,2,3)
(2,3),(1,3) - Total colored are 3 - (1,2,3)
(2,3),(2,3) - Total colored are 2 - (2,3)
```

So there are 0 ways in which exactly 1 ball is painted red, 3 ways in which exactly 2 balls are painted, 6 ways in which exactly 3 balls are painted red.

**What I tried:**
I started with small numbers, took 5 numbers (1,2,3,4,5) and Q = 2, K = 2.

```
(1,2)(1,2) = 2 from the first pair, 0 from the second = 2

(1,2)(1,[3|4|5]) = 2 from the first, +1 from the second = 3, 
and this happens 3 times for each of the numbers mentioned in square braces, 
and the same happens for the below one

(1,2)(2,[3|4|5]) = 2 + 1, happens 3 times

(1,2)(3C2 from [3|4|5]) = 2 + 2, happens 3C2 times
And this is true for all distinct 5C2 pairs. ( please correct me if I'm wrong )
```

Now 5 numbers, Q = 3, K = 2

```
(1,2,3)(1,2,3) = 2 + 0

Change in one number,
(1,2,3)(1,2,[4|5]) = 2 + 1 happens twice

Change in two numbers,
(1,2,3)(1,2C2) = 2 + 2 happens once
```

But when there are more than two turns i.e., when K is 3, I facing difficulties in finding method to make a formula, as I'm weak in Combinatorics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use more standard mathematical notation, $n$ for your `N`, $q$ for your `Q`, and $k$ for your `K`.

By a [Generalised inclusion-exclusion principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1808129), the number of ways to fulfil exactly $j$ out of $n$ conditions is

$$
\sum_{l=j}^n(-1)^{l-j}\binom lj\binom nlb_l\;,
$$

where $b_l$ is the number of ways to fulfil $l$ particular conditions.

Here we have $n$ conditions of a ball staying white. The number of ways of fulfilling $l$ particular ones of them is

$$
b_l=\binom{n-l}q^k\;,
$$

since there are $\binom{n-l}q$ ways to select $q$ balls from the remaining $n-l$ balls, and we do this $k$ times. Thus the number of ways in which exactly $j$ of the balls can remain white is

$$
\sum_{l=j}^n(-1)^{l-j}\binom lj\binom nl\binom{n-l}q^k\;.
$$

In your example with $n=3$, $q=2$, $k=2$, for $j=0$ this is

$$
\sum_{l=0}^3(-1)^{l-0}\binom l0\binom3l\binom{3-l}2^2=\binom32^2-3\binom22^2=6\;,
$$

and for $j=1$ it is

$$
\sum_{l=1}^3(-1)^{l-1}\binom l1\binom3l\binom{3-l}2^2=3\binom22^2=3\;,
$$

in agreement with your results.

Comment: I am a little weak in combinatorics, would you please elaborate it for an example, like how and why would it work for k greater than 3

Comment: @YouKnowWhoIAm: About "how": Exactly the same. $k$ only appears in one place in the result, so you just replace it. About "why": I derived it using the generalized inclusion–exclusion principle in the question that I linked to. The answers to that question contain two references where that principle is derived. If you have questions about those derivations, you can ask them here on the site as separate questions.

Comment: Thank you, can you provide me a website where can solve more problems of this kind, it would be a great help sir

Comment: @YouKnowWhoIAm: I don't know one except for this one, unfortunately.