# Counting the number of strings with at least $2$ numbers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $k$ and $n \ge 3$ be two natural numbers. How many strings in $\{1,...,n\}^k$ contain at least one occurrence of $1$ and $2$, or at least one occurrence of $2$ and $3$ or at least one occurrence of $1$ and $3$?

I tried to break it down and first count the number of strings that contain at least one $1$ which is $n^k - (n-1)^k$ and similarly to at least one $2$ and $3$, but how do we proceed from here?

Comment: It's fine if the string is missing $1$, or any one of $\{1,2,3\}$, it just can't be missing two or three of those.  So, instead of subtracting the ones that are missing single digits, subtract the one ones that are missing at least two.

Comment: As a suggestion:  work out several cases by brute force.  You'll want to check your eventual formula against a healthy list of examples.

Answer (score 2):

Use Inclusion/Exclusion.

Let $A$ be the subset of strings containing at least one $1$.

Let $B$ be the subset of strings containing at least one $2$.

Let $C$ be the subset of strings containing at least one $3$.

Then:

$$|(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C)| = |A\cap B|+|A\cap C|+|B\cap C| - |(A\cap B)\cap(A\cap C)|-|(A\cap B)\cap (B\cap C)|-|(A\cap C)\cap (B\cap C)|+|(A\cap B)\cap (A\cap C)\cap (B\cap C)| = |A\cap B|+|A\cap C|+|B\cap C|-2|A\cap B\cap C|$$

And continuing to break this down:

$$|A\cup B| = |A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$$

$A\cup B$ is the subset of strings containing at least one $1$ or at least one $2$. So, the complement of that is a string that contains neither a $1$ nor a $2$. Thus:

$$|A\cup B| = n^k-(n-2)^k = 2(n^k-(n-1)^k)-|A\cap B|$$

This gives:

$$|A\cap B| = n^k-2(n-1)^k+(n-2)^k$$

Similarly, we can find the other intersections:

$$|A\cap B| = |A\cap C| = |B\cap C|$$

Next, we need to find $|A\cap B\cap C|$.

We have:

$$|A\cup B\cup C| = |A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|$$

$$n^k-(n-3)^k = 3(n^k-(n-1)^k)-3(n^k-2(n-1)^k+(n-2)^k)+|A\cap B\cap C|$$

which yields:

$$|A\cap B\cap C| = n^k-3(n-1)^k+3(n-2)^k-(n-3)^k$$

Thus, the answer to your original question is:

$$|(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C)| = 3(n^k-2(n-1)^k+(n-2)^k)-2(n^k-3(n-1)^k+3(n-2)^k-(n-3)^k) = n^k-3(n-2)^k+2(n-3)^k$$

Answer (score 2):

Define sets $A_1,A_2,A_3,A,B,C$ as follows . . .

- Let $A_1$ be the set of strings containing  $1$ but not $2$ or $3$.$\\[4pt]$

  Let $A_2$ be the set of strings containing $2$ but not $1$ or $3$.$\\[4pt]$

  Let $A_3$ be the set of strings containing $3$ but not $1$ or $2$.$\\[4pt]$

  Let $A=A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3$.$\\[4pt]$

  Let $B$ be the set of strings containing at least one of $1,2,3$.$\\[4pt]$

  Let $C$ be the set of strings containing at least two of $1,2,3$.

The goal is to find $|C|$.

For $1\le i\le 3$, we have $|A_i|=(n-2)^k-(n-3)^k$.

For $|A|$, since $A_1,A_2,A_3$ are disjoint, we get $|A|=3\bigl((n-2)^k-(n-3)^k\bigr)$.

For $|B|$, we get $|B|=n^k-(n-3)^k$.

For $|C|$, we have $|C|=|B|-|A|$, hence $|C|=n^k-3(n-2)^k+2(n-3)^k$.

Comment: This is definitely a simpler formulation of the solution than my answer. +1

Comment: @InterstellarProbe: Perhaps, but my approach is more ad-hoc, while yours (+1) is more of a standard inclusion-exclusion approach, so will benefit the OP to work through as well.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot resist applying the [generalised inclusion exclusion principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1808129/generalised-inclusion-exclusion-principle):

> Given set $A_i$ for $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$, let $n_k=\sum |A_{i(1)}\cap \dots \cap A_{i(k)}|$, where $\{i(1),\dots,i(k)\}$ ranges over all subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ of size $k$. The regular principle of inclusion exclusion says that
> $$
> \text{# elements contained in at least $1$ of the $A_i$}=\sum_{k\ge 1}(-1)^{k-1}n_k
> $$
> More generally,
> $$
> \text{# elements contained in at least $m$ of the $A_i$}=\sum_{k\ge m}(-1)^{k-m}\binom{k-1}{m-1}n_k\tag1
> $$
> $$
> \text{# elements contained in exactly $m$ of the $A_i$}=\sum_{k\ge m}(-1)^{k-m}\binom{k}{m}n_k\tag2
> $$

We will only use $(1)$, but I stated $(2)$ for completeness to show the connection with the linked answer.

In your case, let $A_1$ be the set of strings which do *not* contain $1$, and similarly for $A_2$ and $A_3$. You want to count the number of strings which occur in at most one of the $A_i$ for $i\in \{1,2,3\}$. This is the complement of the set of strings which occur in at least $2$ of the $A_i$, so we can apply $(1)$. We find  $n_2=3(n-2)^k$ and $n_3=(n-3)^k$, so the number of sets missing at least $2$ symbols is
$$
\binom{2-1}{2-1}n_2-\binom{3-1}{2-1}n_3=3(n-2)^k-2(n-3)^k
$$
To get sets missing at most one symbol, subtract this expression from $n^k$.