# Find the probability in 52-card deck

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Find the probability that when a 52-card deck is distributed to four players, the first of them will receive exactly $n$ pairs of "ace and king" of the same suit.

I can calculate cout of possible cases: $\binom{52}{13}$ and count of positive cases for $n=4$: $\binom{4}{4}\binom{44}{5}$ but i dont know how to calculate count of positive cases for $n=1,2,3$

Comment: I suggest trying $n=3$ next.  You have to break it into cases, of course, according to whether or not the player has either the Ace or the King (or neither) in the unique unmatched suit.

Comment: in my opinion for $n=3$ count of positive cases: $\binom{4}{3}\binom{46}{7}$ - $\binom{4}{4}\binom{44}{5}$ but i think its wrong

Comment: As I say, you need to separate out three cases.  The first, wherein the player has neither $A,K$ of the unmatched suit.  The second (resp. third), wherin the player has the $A$ (resp. the $K$) but not both $A,K$ of the unmatched suit.  The second and third cases have the same number (clearly) so you really only have to do two counts.

Comment: $\binom{4}{3}(\binom{44}{7}+2*\binom{44}{6})$ ?

Comment: That's what I get too.  Now do $n=2$ the same way.  Each subcase is trivial, but you need to be careful to make sure you get all the possibilities.

Comment: Should say:  In principle, you could do $n\in \{1,2,3,4\}$ and then deduce $n=0$ by subtraction.  I recommend not doing this, however.  If you do all the cases $n\in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ then you can use the sum as a check. Sadly, though, if the check fails, all you will know is that at least one of the cases is wrong, you won't know which.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E_1$ be the event the first player receives both $\spadesuit\mathsf A$ and $\spadesuit\mathsf K$. Similarly, define $E_2,E_3$ and $E_4$ for the other suits. Using the principle of inclusion-exclusion,
$$
P(\text{no AK})=1-\binom41 P(E_1)+\binom42P(E_1 E_2)-\binom43P(E_1E_2E_3)+\binom44P(E_1E_2E_3E_4)
$$
(I am using the shorthand $P(E_1E_2E_3)$ to mean $P(E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3)$). Furthermore, we can determine
$$
\begin{align}
P(E_1)&=\binom{50}{11}\Big/ \binom{52}{13}\\
P(E_1E_2)&=\binom{48}{9}\Big/\binom{52}{13}\\
P(E_1E_2E_3)&=\binom{46}{7}\Big/\binom{52}{13}\\
P(E_1E_2E_3E_4)&=\binom{44}{5}\Big/\binom{52}{13}
\end{align}
$$
Then, using the [generalized inclusion-exclusion principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1808129/generalised-inclusion-exclusion-principle), we can find the probabiltiy of getting each nonzero number of same suit $AK$'s.
$$
\begin{align}
P(\text{1 AK})
&=\binom41 P(E_1)-
2\binom42 P(E_1E_2)+
3\binom43P(E_1E_2E_3)-
4\binom44P(E_1E_2E_3E_4),
\\
P(\text{2 AK})
&=\binom42 P(E_1E_2)-
3\binom43P(E_1E_2E_3)+
6\binom44P(E_1E_2E_3E_4),
\\
P(\text{3 AK})
&=\binom43P(E_1E_2E_3)-
4\binom44P(E_1E_2E_3E_4),
\\
P(\text{4 AK})
&=\binom44P(E_1E_2E_3E_4)
\end{align}
$$