# Distribution of the size of the union of repeated random draws

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, random, inclusion-exclusion, sampling

I have $d$ items (say numbers 1 to $d$). I would like to uniformly randomly sample $k$ items out of $d$, without replacement. Suppose I do such draws independently $n$ times. I now want to take the *union* of the draws, and I'm interested in the size of this union $u \le kn$.

For example, if $d = 10$, $k = 2$, $n = 3$, I may draw `[[1, 2], [4, 1], [5, 9]]`, and the union is `[1, 2, 4, 5, 9]` and $u = 5$.

**Q: What distribution does $u$ follow, and what are its parameters? Or can we show that there's no closed-form distribution?**

My intuitions:

- If $kn \ll d$, then the $u \approx kn$ since we don't expect too much overlap between the draws, but it becomes tricky as $kn$ gets to a "significant" fraction of $d$ since overlap happens more often.
- Also, since we draw $k$ items without replacement, larger $k$ should mean more frequent overlaps than larger $n$.
- Perhaps $d - u$ follows a Binomial: if considering every item's probability of *not* being drawn (over all the draws) as an independent Bernoulli, then the number of items *not drawn* (i.e. $d - u$) should follow a Binomial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using [inclusion–exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

The probability that $\ell$ particular numbers haven’t been sampled after $n$ draws of $k$ items is

$$
\left(\frac{\binom{d-\ell}k}{\binom dk}\right)^n\;.
$$

Thus, by the [Generalised inclusion-exclusion principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1808129), the probability that exactly $t=d-u$ numbers haven’t been sampled is

$$
\sum_{\ell=t}^d(-1)^{\ell-t}\binom\ell t\binom d\ell\left(\frac{\binom{d-\ell}k}{\binom dk}\right)^n\;.
$$

In your example, with $d=10$, $k=2$, $n=3$, $u=5$ and thus $t=10-5=5$, this probability is

\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\binom{10}2^{-3}\sum_{\ell=5}^{10}(-1)^{\ell-5}\binom\ell5\binom{10}\ell\binom{10-\ell}2^3
\\
&=&
\binom{10}2^{-3}\left(\binom55\binom{10}5\binom52^3-\binom65\binom{10}6\binom42^3+\binom75\binom{10}7\binom32^3-\binom85\binom{10}8\binom22^3\right)
\\
&=&
\frac{1\cdot252\cdot10^3-6\cdot210\cdot6^3+21\cdot120\cdot3^3-56\cdot45\cdot1^3}{45^3}
\\
&=&
\frac{112}{225}
\\[4pt]
&\approx&
50\%\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

For this simple case we could also have calculated the pedestrian way: Choose one of $10$ numbers to double, choose one of $3$ draws in which it doesn’t appear, choose the remaining numbers in one of $\binom94=126$ ways, and distribute them over the three draws in one of $4\cdot3=12$ ways, for a probability of

$$
\frac{10\cdot3\cdot126\cdot12}{\binom{10}2^3}=\frac{112}{225}\;.
$$

*Edit in response to comment:*

As usual, due to the [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties), the expectation and variance are easier to determine than the entire distribution.

The probability that a given number hasn’t been sampled after $n$ draws of $k$ items is

$$
\left(1-\frac kd\right)^n\;,
$$

so by linearity of expectation the expected number of unsampled numbers after $n$ draws is

$$
d\left(1-\frac kd\right)^n\;.
$$

To obtain the variance, let $I_j$ be the indicator variable of the event that the number $j$ hasn’t been sampled. Then $X=\sum_jI_j$ is the number of unsampled numbers, and

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathsf E\left[X^2\right]
&=&
\mathsf E\left[\left(\sum_jI_j\right)^2\right]
\\
&=&
\mathsf E\left[\sum_jI_j^2+\sum_{i\ne j}I_iI_j\right]
\\
&=&
\mathsf E\left[\sum_jI_j+\sum_{i\ne j}I_iI_j\right]
\\
&=&
\mathsf E[X]+\sum_{i\ne j}\mathsf E\left[I_iI_j\right]
\\
&=&
d\left(1-\frac kd\right)^n+d(d-1)\left(\frac{\binom{d-2}k}{\binom dk}\right)^n
\\
&=&
d\left(1-\frac kd\right)^n+d(d-1)\left(\frac{(d-k)(d-k-1)}{d(d-1)}\right)^n
\\
&=&
d\left(1-\frac kd\right)^n+d(d-1)\left(1-\frac kd\right)^n\left(1-\frac{k}{d-1}\right)^n
\end{eqnarray*}

(where the product $I_iI_j$ is the indicator variable of the event that neither $i$ nor $j$ has been drawn), so the variance is

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathsf{Var}\left[X\right]
&=&
\mathsf E\left[X^2\right]-\mathsf E[X]^2
\\
&=&
d\left(1-\frac kd\right)^n+d(d-1)\left(1-\frac kd\right)^n\left(1-\frac{k}{d-1}\right)^n-\left(d\left(1-\frac kd\right)^n\right)^2
\\
&=&
d\left(1-\frac kd\right)^n\left((d-1)\left(1-\frac{k}{d-1}\right)^n+1-d\left(1-\frac kd\right)^n\right)\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

In your example, with $d=10$, $k=2$, $n=3$, these are

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathsf E[X]
&=&
10\left(1-\frac2{10}\right)^3
\\
&=&
\frac{128}{25}
\\[4pt]
&=&
5.12
\end{eqnarray*}

and

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathsf{Var}\left[X\right]
&=&
10\left(1-\frac2{10}\right)^3\left((10-1)\left(1-\frac29\right)^3+1-10\left(1-\frac2{10}\right)^3\right)
\\
&=&
\frac{29696}{50625}
\\[4pt]
&\approx&
0.59\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thank you! This looks like a hairy distribution. How would one go about characterizing the mean & std of the distribution?

Comment: @kzliu: I've added the calculation of the mean and variance.